# scale fit mobile web content using viewport meta tag

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile, viewport

I'm trying to figure out how to leverage the mobile viewport meta tag to automatically zoom the contents of a HTML page to fit into a web view.

Constraints:

- The HTML may or may not have fixed size elements (ex img has a fixed width of 640). In other words I don't want to force the content to be fluid and use %'s.
- I do not know the size of the webview, I just know its aspect ratio

For example, if I have a single image (640x100px) I want the image to zoom out if the webview is 300x250 (scale down to fit).  On the other hand, if the webview is 1280x200 I want the image to zoom in and fill the webview (scale up to fit).

After reading the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) and the [iOS docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html) on viewports, it seems simple: since I know the width of my content (640) I just set the viewport width to 640 and let the webview decide if it needs to scale the content up or down to fit the webview.

If I put the following into my android/iPhone browser OR a 320x50 webview, the image does not zoom out to fit the width.  I can scroll the image to the right and left..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Test Viewport</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=640" />
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,dd,dl,dt,li,ol,ul,fieldset,form,label,legend,button,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td 
    {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 100%;
      line-height: 1;
      font-family: inherit;
      vertical-align: top;
    }       
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="http://www.dmacktyres.com/img/head_car_tyres.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Does the viewport meta tag only zoom into content that is < the  webview area?

Comment: do you have solution for this yet?

Comment: Nope not yet.  I'm guessing no simple solution is possible

Answer (score 59):

In the head add this

```
//Include jQuery
<meta id="Viewport" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  var ww = ( $(window).width() < window.screen.width ) ? $(window).width() : window.screen.width; //get proper width
  var mw = 480; // min width of site
  var ratio =  ww / mw; //calculate ratio
  if( ww < mw){ //smaller than minimum size
   $('#Viewport').attr('content', 'initial-scale=' + ratio + ', maximum-scale=' + ratio + ', minimum-scale=' + ratio + ', user-scalable=yes, width=' + ww);
  }else{ //regular size
   $('#Viewport').attr('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, width=' + ww);
  }
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I think there's a typo in the viewport meta tag. The attribute should be content, not width, right?

Answer (score 20):

I think this should help you.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Tell me if it works.

P/s: here is some media query for standard devices. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: And with that you're going to blatantly make scaling up/zooming in impossible for users with visual impairments, who are not able to read in the font-size chosen by you.

Answer (score 12):

ok, here is my final solution with 100% native javascript:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport">

<script type="text/javascript">
//mobile viewport hack
(function(){

  function apply_viewport(){
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)   ) {

      var ww = window.screen.width;
      var mw = 800; // min width of site
      var ratio =  ww / mw; //calculate ratio
      var viewport_meta_tag = document.getElementById('viewport');
      if( ww < mw){ //smaller than minimum size
        viewport_meta_tag.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=' + ratio + ', maximum-scale=' + ratio + ', minimum-scale=' + ratio + ', user-scalable=no, width=' + mw);
      }
      else { //regular size
        viewport_meta_tag.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, width=' + ww);
      }
    }
  }

  //ok, i need to update viewport scale if screen dimentions changed
  window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    apply_viewport();
  });

  apply_viewport();

}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

For Android there is the addition of target-density tag.

```
target-densitydpi=device-dpi
```

So, the code would look like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
```

Please note, that I believe this addition is only for Android (but since you have answers, I felt this was a good extra) but this *should* work for most mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks, setting target-densitydpi=2 solved my problem like magic.

Comment: target-densitydpi has been removed from WebKit http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/119527

Answer (score 2):

Adding `style="width:100%;max-width:640px"` to the image tag will scale it up to the viewport width, i.e. for larger windows it will look fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a style="width:100%;" to the img tag. That way the image will fill up the entire width of the page, thus scaling down if the image is larger than the viewport.

Comment: yes that solves the problem if everything is fluid, but per my 2nd bullet: "I don't want to force the content to be fluid and use %'s".

Think of an entire website with bunch of items in it - divs, canvas, iframe, etc...

I know the fixed with of the page - I want the webview to zoom in/out to exactly the fixed width I specify.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as yours, but my concern was list view. When i try to scroll list view fixed header also scroll little bit. Problem was **list view height smaller than viewport (browser) height.** You just need to reduce your viewport height lower than content tag (list view within content tag) height.
Here is my meta tag;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=90%,  user-scalable = no">
```

Hope this will help.Thnks.

Answer (score -1):

Here, let me show you what I know:

Glitch's hello-website template uses a meta tag just like this one to rezise content on the template:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It should fix the problem you are having.

P.S: make sure you put it in the head tag!

Answer (score -2):

Sorry about my previous answer, this should explain it a lot better.

The behavior you are experiencing is correct, and it is related to how the viewport meta tag works on mobile browsers. The viewport meta tag is used to control how the web page is displayed on mobile devices, including how it is scaled and sized relative to the viewport of the device.

When you set the viewport width to 640, as you have done in your example, it is effectively setting the width of the layout viewport to 640 pixels. The layout viewport is an imaginary viewport that the mobile browser uses to lay out the web page content. However, this does not necessarily mean that the content will be automatically scaled to fit the webview area.

The behavior you are seeing, where the image does not zoom out to fit the width of the webview, is because the image is larger than the width of the layout viewport (640px). As a result, the image overflows the viewport, and you can scroll horizontally to see the rest of the image.

To achieve the desired behavior of automatically zooming the content to fit into the webview, you can use the "initial-scale" property of the viewport meta tag. The "initial-scale" property allows you to set the initial zoom level of the web page. Setting the "initial-scale" to 1 means that the content will be displayed at its original size, and it will not be scaled.

Here's how you can modify the viewport meta tag to achieve the desired behavior:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=1" />
```

With this modification, the image will be scaled down to fit the width of the webview if it is larger than 640px, and it will be displayed at its original size if the webview is wider than 640px.

Please note that mobile browsers may have variations in how they handle the viewport meta tag, so it's always a good idea to test your web page on different devices and browsers to ensure the desired behavior is consistent across different platforms.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT