# how to set width in android using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout

I have to set the width of the page which is compatible for all size of Android device . 
  For which i used the following code:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
```

also I tried the `target-densityDpi` with all the properties, also in the `target-densityDpi`, i gave number between 70 and 400

the width doesn't fit the screen, either the width overflows the screenwidth (in smaller screen display) or the width is too small (in the bigger display that is in  4' to 5' inch display android device)

Answer (score 0):

I have about the same problem. I use:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
```

and:

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no"
```

And with all variations, `"` instead of `'` 
also semicolons between the declarations...but I can still scale in my android device, And move the content half of the page.

may be with javascript? see...
[scale fit mobile web content using viewport meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735457/scale-fit-mobile-web-content-using-viewport-meta-tag)

regards, Anne

Answer (score 0):

I solve a similar problem by using:

`<meta charset = "utf-8" name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, user-scalable = no, target-densitydpi=mdpi">`

and also a css with:

```
body {
   width: 100%;
}
```

with `mdpi` I avoid the problem of too small fonts. If you do not have problem with fonts you can also try `device-dpi`