# How to optimize an HTML 5 game for Mobile application?

Tags: android, html, cordova, responsive-design

I am trying to optimize the below HTML5 Game for Mobile with Cordova (http://cordova.apache.org/).

http://percsich.hu/TululooGames/skeet/index.html.

So i have few questions for my clarification.

1. I have created a build for the above game and it is working in the emulator. But the shooter game is very slow in the emulator. I do not know how to resolve this. But the same in the browser is working fine.
2. Another important thing is the screen size. The game is not fit into the emulator screen size. I have added meta tag like below

meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height"

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

But it is not fit with the emulator screen. Half-of-the screen only i can see in the emulator.

Please suggest on this so it should fit to all the screen size.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. the HTML5 file game built with CANVAS tag and JS.

Comment: do u test on andorid emulator?

Comment: Yes. Correct. I am using Android emulator (adt-bundle-windows-x86).

Answer (score 0):

1) set hardwareAccelerated true in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

2) Start Emulator with Use Host GPU [image]

3) [Improving the Performance of Phonegagap app](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/03/11/performance-ux-considerations-for-successful-phonegap-apps/)

4) [Improving the Performance of your HTML5 App](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/)

5) [scale fit for mobile view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735457/scale-fit-mobile-web-content-using-viewport-meta-tag)

Comment: Hi, where do i find the "AndroidManifest.xml" file. I am using windows 7 installed with Node.js and cordova. Thanks.

Comment: Do u have android project ?

Comment: No... i am using Cordova which uses html5, css and js to create android applications. i searched to the all files and folders for the keyword "AndroidManifest.xml". No match.

Comment: how to run your project in android emulator

Comment: First i create a platform using the command - <project file directory> / cordova platform add android; and i create a build using <project file directory> / cordova build -d android; Finally i open the project using the emulator <project file directory> / cordova emulate android. Thanks.

Comment: @Yadheendran Your manifest is in /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml (of your cordova project). The android:hardwareAccelerated="true" flag is already active by default.