# Disable zoom on mobile devices for fixed viewport size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to disable zoom on mobile devices.
I know this code will work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

But in my case, i have not the option to use "width=device-width". I have to set the viewport size to 480px so i am using the following code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480px, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

But i get a zoomed in view of the page on mobile device and i am able to zoom it out.

Comment: did you tried like this content="width=480, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"

Comment: yes, i get the same result as 480px

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using "target-densitydpi=device-dpi" and hence the code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no" />
```

fixed my problem. Thanks to [Dave Rook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789836/1860859)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better use 100% instead of 480

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem recently where when I first load my page I need it to be completely shown on the mobile devices, but it was constantly being zoomed in at exactly the width of the device based on my fixed viewport width. Here is what I had:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=820", initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I removed the `initial-scale=1.0` and there was no issue afterward. You can of course still use the `user-scalable=no` to keep from being able to zoom as you requested.

Comment: @Symbolwdd I looked at Dave Rook's answer with the answer you have and it's no longer valid. Here is the change on [target-densitydpi](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/119527/webkit).