# Viewport zoom bounce

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

I have added this code and it works almost the way it should:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

The problem that has occured now is, when I zoom in with my mobile device, it zooms in but bounces back to original width, so it is a progress that it returns to original width but I have seen websites which is stiff and not possible to zoom at all, how can I achieve that?

I want it to not zoom no matter if I double press or take two fingers and try to zoom it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860498/disable-zoom-on-mobile-devices-for-fixed-viewport-size or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari But I do not see huge differences

Comment: None of them worked, it still zooms in and bounces out. I want it totally stiff

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag posted in the first post is correct, what fixed this was adding this in html tag in css

```
position:absolute; width:99%;
```

Hope this helps anyone out there!