# How to Avoid Media Queries Forever?

Tags: android, html, ios, css

I don't like media queries, I think it's a terrible idea.

I want to make an app for ONLY phones. So my app will look the same in all cases, but all I'm trying to do is just rescale the app for the different screens. That's it!

Now I don't like EMs, and I don't like percentage widths. All those ideas sound terrible. I like VW/VH http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units but ios safari doesn't support this yet.

So my other idea is to make a pixel based static app. For example think of a calculator that is 400px by 400px in height. And everything else is sized in pixels.

Can I just take this, and set up a viewport that fits my static content but stretches it to the viewports size? I think this is possible as the viewport supports zooming, no?

Comment: you asked more or less the same the same a few days ago and I explained you the pros and cons . Why don't you do it and try it?

Comment: This is different. I'm asking if I make static content can I do the fitting via a viewport.

Comment: I didn't like answer that included both vw/vh and scaling the content via transforms. it doesn't sound right. and yes, I need to try this but wondering if anyone can save me some time esp if what i'm saying doesn't sound reasonable.

Comment: So, you want a responsive(fluid) site, but don't want to use the responsive (fluid) techniques... That is a little hard...

Comment: I just want to "scale" a program basically. everything is too hard out there. and I don't want to deal with percentages within div, it's too convoluted.

Comment: You can, actually use a CSS transform effect on the most parent element, like `transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);` where the first argument is the horizontal scale, and the second is the vertical scale. But that is just visual, and might get blurry...

Comment: no, I want to do with with the viewport, not the transforms... is it possible with the viewport? kind of like <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">

Comment: the problem is you don't "like" technically correct answers, you don't "like" commonly accepted and tested approaches, you don't "like" anything that is already known, so you're basically asking people to try new things for you because, by your own words "you don't want to lose time". Well, I will follow this question just to see if you get any answer because the question (despite your lack of effort, code, etc) is interesting, but I doubt you'll get any answer

Comment: @LcSalazar : I gave him the transform answer with code and explanation a few days ago and he had me back and forth for hours. He didn't "like" it

Comment: haha, fabio you're right for being upset in a way. but all the solutions out there are no good. although I did like the vh/vw but I'm ahead of my time here. but i'm gonna do alot of research and i'll eventually answer my question. just will take me a few hours vs if someone just knows and can tell me. (transforms usually don't scale nicely though...)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

...and then use width:100% style for all your container elements.

edit: the fact that you 'don't like' percentages. It's the solution to your problem though.

Comment: 400px is 400px. That's it. You could zoom the page by changing the scale, but never will it stretch correctly on both sides. Percentages is the best case scenario. You should also use 'box-sizing: border-box;' so that you don't encounter any problems with percentages and margins/paddings/borders.

Comment: percentages are evil because then you need to deal with parent/child relationships. so a child's 100% width is in relation to it's parents. i NEED vh/vw. argh, i hate my life.

Comment: don't be picky and learn how to use all the commands. It's not a matter of what 'you like'. You might not like hammers, but it's the only tool that can be used to put a nail in wood. That's it. Also what you used as an 'answer' of your own was mentioned in my answer as well, that you can use scale. However using js, to do what pure css can do leads to significant drop of performance

Comment: it's not about being picky as much as it is understanding that the current way that css/html for resizing sucks balls. that's what vh/vw is trying to solve but doesn't work well on mobile, now that's funny. em, percentages, pixels, media queries, the viewport -- all of it is a bunch of garbage esp for mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

found out sort'of what I'm looking for

[scale fit mobile web content using viewport meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735457/scale-fit-mobile-web-content-using-viewport-meta-tag)

Especially the answer by Bren1818 where he programmatically calculates the initial-scale of the viewport. Although I'm not sure I like this answer either... wish vh/vw units would get on to mobile already.