# Responsive CSS overflow issue

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a responsive site that is somehow having a strange overflow area/issues that shouldn't be happening.  It is going to need a real expert set of eyes to find the issue, I'm stumped.

The html, body, and body `#wrapper` widths are all set based on device size, and their overflow-x is set to hidden so there should be NO OVERFLOW area at all, yet it persists as a brown area to the right side of the narrow page designs.

In iOS they display at the proper zoom, but you can scroll right into the brown overflow area.

On Android devices the pages start really zoomed out and include the brown overflow area.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing this overflow area as the width and max-width are explicitly set and overflow-x is set to hidden so nothing should extend past the page container.

The site can be viewed at http://gowestyoungmom.com/.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this part of your css(`responsive.css line 175`)

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 360px) and (min-device-width: 331px)
html, html body, body #wrapper 
{
    width: 330px !important;
    min-width: 320px !important;
    max-width: 360px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and replace with this

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 360px) and (min-device-width: 331px)
html, html body, body #wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    min-width: 0 !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this did help some.

the overflow area is no longer there as it is now filled with the body.
It doesn't solve the overall issue though.

The page still starts zoomed out on Android and also on iOS now.  Instead of displaying at the intended width now the narrow column is down the middle.  So still the wrong width, now in both iOS and Android.  One step forward, two steps back.

You can see an image of this here:
http://redesigned.com/misc/GWYM_01.png
(i couldn't figure a way to add images to the comments...sorry.)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Apply those style and add this ` initial-scale=1.0` to viewport meta.

Comment: I had initial-scale=1.0 in my viewport tag when i made the suggested changes and left the comment above.  that didn't resolve the issue.

I just tried added a viewport resize javascript function from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735457/scale-fit-mobile-web-content-using-viewport-meta-tag

but it seems like i am still hitting an issue as the page sometimes is off center as it is still wider then the viewport.  if i can figure out the original issue that should fix and possibly prevent needing such a workaround.  thoughts?  i really need some help figuring this out. :-(

Comment: @JoshuaJarman I'm sorry to replay late. You don't need to use javascript. You can do it by media query and viewport.

Comment: I won't be able to check back until tomorrow, but please feel free to leave any additional suggestions and would love to make it work without the javascript workaround.  right now i set staggered max-widths and the javascript and have it working in mobile chrome and safari, but not mobile firefox.  thank you so much for the assistance, it is very much appreciated.