# How to display a web page fully in android webview which is not displaying completely even in native browsers

Tags: android, webview

I'm giving a link to a website (For example: http://istqb.in/istqb-foundation/syllabi) in my android App.
This webpage is not displaying properly the tables in it. Right side part is truncating.
View in my webview in App and native browser is same. Is there any way I can display the page fully; probably with a horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: It is not about the `webview` problem. It is about the html/css!

Comment: The site may not be compatible with mobile phones.It's build only for desktop view.The issue is with the html/css as Nguyen Doan Tung said.

Answer (score 1):

Like this way you can set some setting on webview and horizotalscrollbar for it for more [read this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html)

```
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
  mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
  mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

You can set DomStorageEnable as well hardware acceleration as per requirement based up on which kind of content on webpage same way you can load it on Chromeview or webview client

Comment: Thanks Ajay for quick reply.
When I tried, I'm getting error like:
Error:(661, 25) error: cannot find symbol method setDomStorageEnabled(boolean)

Comment: remove that line this is just sample not compulsory to set it

Comment: After this additional code, in pages where the contents were wrapping it not wrapping text. However the problematic URL remains same.

Answer (score 0):

**you can do with use of Web View Client like below code write in oncreate() method**

```
String url= "write your url here";
WebView vistaWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);      vistaWeb.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser()); vistaWeb.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
     vistaWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      vistaWeb.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
       vistaWeb.loadUrl(url);
```

**Now make new inner class like below**

```
 private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     view.loadUrl(url);
     return true;
  }   }
```

Comment: I think your website table code not write properly. if you see all text and all it will wrap in mobile view. but table not wrap

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735457/scale-fit-mobile-web-content-using-viewport-meta-tag

Comment: @Vishal.Thanks for your time.
Might be the website code is not proper. 
Other mobile browsers too behave same (Truncate towards right).
For the other link; it seems if I have control over webpage, I need to add viewport. However it is not in my control.

Comment: hmm. it helpfull i think for you.i cant exactly told that was mistake but i think it should be mistake

Comment: Yes, the link is very helpful. Thanks Vishal for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setInitialScale(100);
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
```